# How can I animate algebraic manipulation, preferably in Python

Tags: python, animation, math, latex

I need to be able to start with an algebraic expression and show how to manipulate it to obtain a different expression - moving the elements around, changing signs, dividing both sides by the same scalar, for example. So if I started with this expression:

[image]

And wanted to end up with this one:

[image]

Then I would move the B1 and B2Xi to the other side and change their signs. But I would like this process to be animated, so you actually see the path of the B's as they arc up and over to the opposite side and the + signs transform into - signs.

There's a tutorial on doing this in PowerPoint here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ksw0LUVu-Gw. But it is very laborious. I'd prefer to be able to write reusable code and speed up the process. Also, if the equations can be as pretty as they are in Latex, that would be a bonus.

SOme of the equations I'll be animating get pretty intricate and complex too, so not all as simple as the example here.

Is there a way of doing this? Preferably in Python, but I could also learn how to do it another package if it was not too steep a learning curve.

Thanks

Comment: My gut says this would be a lot less painful in javascript than in python. That being said, in python you could use pygame for a live animation, or PIL/Pillow to save an animation as a gif.

Comment: If you like LaTeX, you could also use **beamer**, which is basically LaTeX's answer to powerpoint. Maybe this question can help: [Tikz animated equation in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55216/tikz-animated-equation-in-beamer)

Comment: Googling for "animate latex equation" returned [this gitlab repository](https://gitlab.com/agrahn/animate): "A LaTeX package for creating portable, JavaScript driven PDF and SVG animations from sets of vector graphics or raster image files or from inline graphics." It appears to have good documentation, but unfortunately no graphic example of an animation produced with it.

Comment: Whether your get good answers or not: When you have a working solution by yourself, would you please consider writing an answer to your own question? Given the sanitary context, this might be incredibly useful. My current best approach to teach over videoconf is using a Jupyter Notebook (because it combines markdown+latex+python, can be executed live, and produces a document to give to the students at the end of the class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may like to consider 3Blue1Brown's Manim. Here's a great tutorial on how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI2YJff9SgI&ab_channel=TheoremofBeethoven

It is a steep learning curve, but any solution will be it you want it to be general and reusable. If this is a one off, I'd stick with powerpoint.